# PHP file include stops execution

Tags: php, html, include

I have the following code inside the body of my index.php page:

```
echo "Begin <br />";
include('test.shtml');
echo "Importing dbRead.php here <br />";
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/dbRead.php');
echo "We have included dbRead.php here <br />";
```

The output on the page is:

Begin 
Inside test.shtml 
Importing dbRead.php here

The files are all in the same directory. What's going on?

EDIT: dbRead.php is a class. It is parsed just fine by my WAMP server, but not the web server after I upload. It contains a single class with properly formed methods and a constructor.

Comment: I forgot to add that inside test.shtml is just: Inside test.shtml

Comment: - You can edit your question (instead commenting) - Whats inside `dbRead.php`? - Whats the problem? As far as I can see everything works fine.

Comment: Also it works on my WAMP server, but not when I posted to the web server.

Comment: Your example code has no `include_once()` as mentioned in the title. Should your problem be that after the `dbRead` include nothing happens, and the following echo seemingly doesn't work either, then it might be a error (or just an `exit;`) in the referenced script. Try to raise the `error_reporting` just to see.

Comment: and where is `include_once` in the code

Comment: You should try adding error_reporting(E_ALL) to the top of the script and see if any errors are spit out by php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I see all the echos are executed before `include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/dbRead.php');`, but no echo output is visible after that. There are some possibilities, for example:

- in `dbRead.php` you use for example `ob_start();` (see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/function.ob-start.php)), thus the echo is executed, but not sent to the browser,
- you have some error that terminates the script in `dbRead.php`, but you have error reporting turned off (see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/function.error-reporting.php)),
- you invoked `exit` (see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/function.exit.php)) or `die()` (see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/function.die.php)) within the included file,

Comment: There was an error in the dbRead.php. Still don't understand WHY there is an error, but there it is.

Comment: Hahaha the server is old only supported PHP4 >.<

Answer (score 1):

Based on your output the issue isn't the `include`s (btw, `dirname(__FILE__)` is unnecessary unless the file itself (index.php) is also included by another file)... the issue is you have an error in `dbRead.php` or it doesn't exist, or it stops further execution (with `exit` `die` etc).

Does your DIR look like:

```
/
/index.php
/test.shtml
/dbRead.php
```

?? Or are you expecting the `dirname(__FILE__)` to shift the directory in some way?